# How to return a new instance every time doReturn is called?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have the following test case:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(...);
doReturn(resource.getInputStream()).when(someMock).getInputStream();
```

where I read some resource and return it in my test. This method is called with some uncertainty in an asynchronous, scheduled manner in the actual production code - hence I do not have complete control over how many times it is *exactly* called, although the returned data is always the same (or should be).

In other words, this can *potentially* cause a randomly failing test if the method is invoked and the stream is read more times than expected, since the stream has not (and cannot) be reset, and is already at `EOF`.

I explicitly do *not* wish to have this be invoked synchronously in the test context, and am using `Awaitility.await()` to test these kinds of scenarios, so unfortunately that is not an option for me.

Now, the 'dumb' way to potentially fix this is something like the following:

```
doReturn(resource.getInputStream()).doReturn(resource.getInputStream()).<...>.when(someMock).getInputStream();
```

But this still does not fix the actual issue and is a band-aid at best.

I was actually expecting something like the following to work:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(...);
doReturn(resource.call().getInputStream()).when(someMock).getInputStream();
```

but unfortunately, this also retrieves the underlying Stream only once.

How can I provide a fresh instance on every `doReturn()` call? Can mockito even do this? Is there an alternative approach to what I wish to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I'm on board with what you're asking.

You're first doing `ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(...);`, which I'm assuming is a one time thing. And then you are returning `resource.getInputStream()` for every invocation. By definition, you can't have multiple instances then - you're asking for one thing and trying to do another. So what is it that you want? You could use some question restructuring. Also, what are you doing with `ClassPathResource` in a unit test in the first place?

In the meantime, the best I can guess of what you want is the most literal interpretation of your question that I can get to, and completely ignoring any and all psudeo-code (because it completely contradicts your question). That is, you want a completely separate instance of an `InputStream` for every invocation to a method. This part is easy.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<InputStream>() {
            @Override
            public InputStream answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                    throws Throwable {
                return Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
            }
        }).when(resource.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is, in fact, a snippet from an integration test - usually the data would be provided via S3. Hence the `ClassPathResource` was representative of the same data that would be downloaded from there during normal execution. The `doAnswer` solution seems to be the way to go. I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I might be a bit too simple to maybe understand your test, but if you're doing an integration test and thereby are using a true `ClassPathResource` then I'm not sure the use of `Mockito#doAnswer(Answer)` will help. I almost hesitate to say that because as I say, I might not be totally grasping what you have going on. It seems like you still will end up returning `resource.getInputStream()` from the answer right? If so, then it's still the same result as `doReturn(resource.getInputStream()).when(someMock).getInputStream()`

Comment: In general, this is why I disagree with integration tests using JUnit done in parallel. You end up with a lot of conflicting state of the tests all interacting with the same things and expecting different results. The only way it can really be done is in serial. It's just the nature of trying to run an integration test on a stateful program.

Comment: Oh I think I see. It's because `resource.getInputStream()` returns a new `InputStream` on every call. If that's true, then yes, `Answer` will work fine.

Comment: Bit late, but this did indeed solve my current problem. I additionally rewrote the tests a bit so that they're not random in the previous sense, so I shouldn't encounter this problem again. Thank you for the quick reply!